# How to add Latitude and Longitudes to ArrayList in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, arraylist

I have a task in which the app uses `LocationManager` and `GPS_PROVIDER` to listen fro location's `Latitude` and `Longitude` and store it in a temporary memory in a time interval. And when the temporary memory reaches six `LatLngs` then it'll send it's contents to a mobile number via `SMS` and contents will have to become `null`.
I used the following code

```
 private void sendLog() {
    Toast.makeText(MainPage.this,"Sending Log",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final SharedPreferences account=getSharedPreferences("admins",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String interval=account.getString("lti", "");
    int timeInterval=Integer.parseInt(interval);

    LocationManager logManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    logManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            double latitude=location.getLatitude();
            double longitude=location.getLongitude();
            DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
            Date date=new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
            String time=sdf.format(date);

                List<String> loglist = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i=1;i<=6;i++){
                loglist.add("!+" + dFormat.format(latitude) + ",+" + dFormat.format(longitude) + "," + time);
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainPage.this,loglist.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (loglist.size()==6){
                StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
                for (int j=0;j<loglist.size();j++){
                    log.append(loglist.get(j).toString());
                }

               SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(logPreferences.getString("admin1",""),null,log.toString(),null,null);
            }
        }
```

This code gets LatLng and sends sms with six values without failure. But the problem is it adds only one latitude and longitude value in all places of array list. I don't want to get same value in all paces. I want six different Latitude and Longitude values in the ArrayList. If anyone know how to do this please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you loop the same location 6 times, try this code:

```
            List<String> loglist = new ArrayList<String>(); // declare your list outside the listener, or make it as class variable.   
            LocationManager logManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                logManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                        double latitude=location.getLatitude();
                        double longitude=location.getLongitude();
                        DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
                        Date date=new Date();
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
                        String time=sdf.format(date);

                        Toast.makeText(MainPage.this,loglist.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (loglist.size()==6){// you reach 6 values => send the SMS
                            StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
                            for (int j=0;j<loglist.size();j++){
                                log.append(loglist.get(j).toString());
                            }

                           SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
                            smsManager.sendTextMessage(logPreferences.getString("admin1",""),null,log.toString(),null,null);
                        } else {// you can add more location
                           loglist.add("!+" + dFormat.format(latitude) + ",+" + dFormat.format(longitude) + "," + time);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<String> loglist = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=1;i<=6;i++){
        if(!loglist.contains(dFormat.format(latitude)+","+dFormat.format(longitude)+","+time))  //if not already added then add it
        loglist.add(dFormat.format(latitude)+","+dFormat.format(longitude)+","+time);
        }
```

check if the value is not already added or not, if not then add it